# wp_signon by user's login by their particular role

Tags: authentication

I am using below script to login to users. And redirecting them to their profile page. This is working fine.

```
$user = wp_signon( 
               array( 
                  'user_login' => $_POST['user-name'], 
                  'user_password' => $_POST['password'] 
               )
            , false );
    
   if ( is_wp_error($user) ) {
    
       echo $user->get_error_message();
   } else {
      # Redirect to account page after successful login.
    if ( $user->ID ) {
    
       wp_set_current_user( $user->ID, $user->name );
         wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->ID, true, false );
         wp_redirect( home_url('profile') );      
    }
```

Now what I want from here is to check the role and if its not the same then don't allow them to login.

I have tried to research to put condition somewhere in this function `wp_signon` to check without any luck so far.

Can someone guide me please how can I achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Add code below wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->ID, true, false ); */

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

if($current_user->roles[0]=='personal_account'){

   wp_redirect(site_url('/profile'));

}else if($current_user->roles[0]=='corporate_user'){

   wp_redirect(site_url('/corporate-profile'));
                    
}
```